# О нотация, разбор определения

Tags: алгоритм

Читаю Седживка, до этого момента было все понятно:

> Говорят, что функция g(N) имеет порядок O(f(N)), если существуют такие
>   постоянные c0 и N0, что g(N) < c0 * f(N) для всех N > N0.

Набор слов, объясните пожалуйста что к чему в этом определении.

Гуглил, сложилось мнение что просто отбрасывают все коэффициенты кроме такого, который растет больше всех при росте входных данных.

Comment: Там же написано, что изучаемая функция g(N) не превосходит функцию f(N), которая ограничивает ее сверху. У вас с пониманием текста проблемы? Еще там написано, что это утверждение верно для всех N > N0. То есть до N0 функция может вести себя как угодно, но начиная с некоторого N0 ее поведение стабилизируется, и можно говорить о ее порядке роста.

Comment: @typemoon где вы такой текст нашли? Я на 56 странице.

Comment: Я перевел на русский язык это определение и вспомнил, что такое порядок роста из курса анализа.

Comment: Про порядки роста проще всего написано здесь http://www.mathprofi.ru/metody_resheniya_predelov_neopredelennosti.html

Comment: @typemoon , я купил эту книгу с переводом, очень жалею что не купил  на англ оригинал. Спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нотация `O(f)` часто используется для описания скорости роста функций в виде `O(N)`(`O(N*N)`, `O(log(N))` и т.д. и т.п.). Фактически, это означает, что некоторая `g(N)` *возрастает не быстрее*, чем линейная (квадратичная, логарифмическая, ... ) функция от `N` с некоторыми коэффициентами.

Например, функция `g(N) = 4*N` имеет порядок `O(N)`, т.к. мы можем записать соотношение `g(N) < 10*N` и это соотношение будет справедливым для любых `N > 1`. В этом примере `c0 = 10`, а `N0 = 1`.

А вот еще один пример, для более сложной функции `g`. Пусть `g(N) = 2*N*N + N`. Эта функция имеет порядок `O(N*N)`, поскольку для любого `N > 1` справедливо `g(N) < 4*N*N`. В этом примере `c0 = 4`, а `N0 = 1`.

На самом деле, параметры `c0` и `N0` могут быть произвольными, но должны быть конечными и не зависеть от `N`.

Сама нотация, полезна при описании сложности алгоритмов. В этом случае она показывает как растет число действий, выполняемых алгоритмом от количества входных данных. При этом, точное количество итераций, обычно, не столь существенно. Важно лишь некоторое *оценочное* значение.

Например, если есть две функции (алгоритма) сортировки массивов, одна из которых имеет порядок `O(N)`, а другая `O(N*N)`, то первая функция *эффективнее* чем вторая.

Comment: @DmitrySimushev  Как 4 в 10 превратили? Вы имеете введу g(N) = O(f(N)) (тут f(N) какая то точная оценка со всеми коэффициентами, а g(N) результат функции O(f(N)) ) и при увеличении N, f(N) возрастет не больше чем g(N) те O(f(N))? А как понимать остальные переменные в определении вопроса?

Comment: `10` это как раз коэффициент `c0`. Он, кстати, может быть любым, главное чтобы не зависел от `N`. Коэффициент `N0` в моем примере равен нулю. Таким образом, с указанными коэффициентами, можно сказать, что `4*N = O(N)`

Comment: @DmitrySimushev Пожалуйста, объясните какую роль играет N0 в этой системе?

Comment: `N0`, фактически, задает область, в которой выполняется соотношение `g(N) < c0*N`. Например, в моем примере выше, соотношение `4*N < 10*N` будет, очевидно, выполняться только для положительных `N`. В реальных случаях функция `g(N)` может иметь куда более сложный вид, поэтому и вводится некая _нижняя граница_ для `N`.

Comment: @DmitrySimushev Спасибо, а то что я написал в комментарии первом, верно? Мне кажется нет, в книге g(N) < c0 * f(N), а я рассчитывал на то, что этот коэффициент, который растет не в зависимости от N, содержит уже в себе функция f(N).

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш первый комментарий. Если говорить о случае, когда `g(N) = 4*N`, то `g(N)` _имеет порядок_ `O(f(N))`, где `f(N) == N`. Говорить о том, что `g(N) = O(f(N))`, на мой взгляд, не верно в принципе (т.е. `g(N)` не _равняется_ результату вычисления `O(f(N))`).

Comment: Как понять имеет порядок? И зачем ввели функцию f(N) раз она и так равна N?

Comment: `f(N)` может быть любой функцией. `f(N) == N` - это только в моем примере с `g(N) = 4*N`. Что значит _имеет порядок_ - описано в приведенном вами определении. Это понятие, как я уже сказал, часто используется при оценке качества алгоритмов и сравнении их эффективности.

Comment: @DmitrySimuhev , в первой задаче g(N) < 4*N^3 можно сделать и так(отношение не изменится), тогда O(N^3) вместо O(N^2) получится или есть какое то  правило на счет f(N)?

Answer (score 4):

Ответ верный. Приведу только пример, который, имхо, сделает его чуть понятней.
Пусть `g(N) = N*N + log(N)` Тогда *порядок* `g(N)` будет `O(N*N)` т.к. при `N0 = 1` и `C0 = 2` для любого N>N0 `g(N) < C0 * N*N` истинно.

Просто во всех ранее приводимых примерах `f(N) == g(N)`, что, видимо, немного сбивает с толку.

Comment: @andry.37 , в вашем примере можно сделать g(N) < C0 * N^3, тогда отношение сохраняется и O(N^3) становится, вместо O(N^2). Или есть правило что необходимо f(N) взять как некий коэффициент который содержит g(N)?

Comment: Хороший, кстати, вопрос! Сейчас освежу в памяти понятие "О большое"

Comment: Не нашел примеров, но похоже Вы правы. Если говорить о сложности алгоритмов, то задача обычно состоит в том, чтобы оценить сложность *снизу*. Т.е. если для функции `g(n)` можно сказать, что она имеет порядок `O(n^x)` то верным будет и удтверждение, что она имеет порядок и `O(n^y)` для любого `y>x`. Иначе, более верным будет сказать, что "g(n) имеет порядок не более чем..."