# Подсчет количества совпадение в списке

Tags: c#, list

Есть список слов. Хочу получить результирующий словарь в котором я бы мог получить количество одинаковых строк. Т.е. словарь будет содержать `{слово;количество совпадений}.`

Данный код делает это, но ооочень медленно. Что я не так сделал, что оно так тормозит

```
var file = File.ReadAllLines(@"1.txt").ToList();

var result = file
  .Select(str => new { Name = str, Count = file.Count(s => s == str) })
  .Where(obj => obj.Count > 1)
  .Distinct()
  .ToDictionary(obj => obj.Name, obj => obj.Count);
```

Comment: Добавьте пример входных данных и результат, который хочется получить.

Comment: проблема в том, что в этом варианте, вы для каждого слова проверяете все слова из файла, т.е. сложность O(N^2), хотя эта задача решается за O(N) с использованием Dictionary, явным циклом, и без LiNQ

Comment: @rdorn не могли подсказать кодом как это делается?

Comment: @rdorn сложность — O(N^2 + N)

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk +N особой роли тут не играет, тормозит квадрат. Там по факту два последовательных алгоритма: подсчет количества и выборка неуникальных, к выборке претензий нет, она линейная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь словарем. Он обеспечивает быстрый поиск по ключу. В данном случае мы будем проверять существует ли слово в словаре. Если не существует — добавляем его, а счетчик устанавливаем в 1. И если существует — делаем поиск по ключу и увеличиваем счетчик на 1. Главной особенностью словарей, является то, что они имеют уникальные ключи, которые получаются путем извлечения хэш-кода значения. Формируется таблица хэш-кодов, которая обеспечивает быстрый поиск.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"1.txt")){
    if (dict.ContainsKey(line)){
        dict[line]++;   
    } else {
        dict.Add(line, 1);  
    }
}
```

Как подсказал @VladD

> По идее, лучше обойтись без материализации списка: ReadLines вместо
>   ReadAllLines.

Сложность выполнения вашего кода будет равна O(N^2), а при использовании словаря — O(N).

Comment: обогнали =) только добавьте немного теоретических сведений, почему это быстрее и в чем фишка Dictionary

Comment: По идее, лучше обойтись без материализации списка: `ReadLines` вместо `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: @rdorn я могу удалить ответ, или заменить на другой с GroupBy

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk зачем сразу удалять то. Я не охочусь за репутацией любыми средствами =)

Comment: @rdorn я не видел комментариев, когда писал ответ

Comment: Вы же хотели написать `File.ReadLines` вместо `Console.ReadLines`?

Comment: @Nikita, да. Спасибо, не заметил)

Comment: Вот нашел, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461251/198316 так что корректная запись оценки сложности будет O(N*N) или O(N^2) ну и другие источник по O-нотации говорят тоже самое.

Comment: @rdorn,  спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Ну да, будет тормозить, у вас квадратичный алгоритм. Вы на каждой итерации перечитываете список заново.

Вам поможет `GroupBy`:

```
File.ReadLines(path)
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())
```

---

Если вам нужно выкинуть уникальные строки, нужно немного длиннее:

```
File.ReadLines(path)
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .Select(g => (value: g.Key, count: g.Count()))
    .Where(t => t.count > 1)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.value, t => t.count)
```

Comment: эм... "а что так можно было?" (с)перто =)

Comment: Только вот пробовал еще и этот метод)))

Comment: @rdorn: Ага, `GroupBy` делает по идее под капотом то же, что и в первом ответе. Так что вручную, думаю, всё равно будет эффективнее.

Comment: В ручную многое эффективнее, только читать иногда на порядок сложнее, тут баланс важен, если не нужна экстремальная производительность, то лучше так

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk: Вы всё равно успели первым :)